# Exporting C++ DLL to Visual Basic

Tags: c++, vb.net, directshow

I am working on a C++ DLL  with DirectShow ... however, It is working fine and records when i initialize the pointers in function start().

I decided to add a function stop so I initialized the pointers in private members ( noting that I tried initializing them as public but doesn't work) in order to access them from any function.

However, when I call it from VB.NET it brings memory access violation. noting that it was working when I initialized the variables in the function itself .

Code Sample

```
#pragma once
#include <dshow.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

class camera
{
private:
    int cameraIndex = 0;
    string Recording_Path ="";
    IEnumMoniker* pEnum =NULL;
    IMoniker* pMoniker = NULL;
    IBaseFilter* pCap = NULL;
    IGraphBuilder* pGraph = NULL;
    ICaptureGraphBuilder2* pBuild = NULL;
    IMediaControl* pControl =NULL;
    IBaseFilter* pMux =NULL;



public:
    camera();
    void set_Params(int index, string RecPath);
    HRESULT InitCaptureGraphBuilder(IGraphBuilder** ppGraph, ICaptureGraphBuilder2** ppBuild);
    HRESULT EnumerateDevices(REFGUID category, IEnumMoniker** ppEnum);
    void DisplayDeviceInformation(IEnumMoniker* pEnum, IMoniker** iMon);
    string convertToString(char* a, int size);
    void Record();
    void Stop();
};
```

Comment: Do you know if the problem is within the dll or at the VB/native interop interface?  Have you tried running it in the debugger in mixed mode so that you can step into native code?

Comment: @Craig I guess it might be something in the vb interop interface... or the exporting way from the c++ side ... I enabled the native debuger but doesn't show any thing ... it just steps into compiler code not mine ...

Comment: You might need to set a breakpoint inside the routine, rather than relying on stepping into it.  If you find that the problem is at the interface, you should add the VB side declarations, since they become very important to troubleshooting.